# TintColor not changing for UIBarButtonItem for .normal stage in case of iOS 13.2

Tags: swift, ios13, swift5, xcode11, ios13.2

I have tried the almost max solution and it did not help, selected state color is applying but for a normal state, it's not applying. This issue I am facing specifically in iOS13.2 only.

```
        tabBarItem.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: tabFont,
                                       NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.yellow],
                                      for: .selected)
    tabBarItem.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: tabFont,
                                       NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white],
                                      for: UIControl.State.normal)
```

I have disabled the dark mode in plist. It always shows as grayed out.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried this? : self.tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = .lightGray

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear what the question is. It's a bug, or at least a serious behavior change, in iOS 13.

To see this, just make new project from the Tabbed App template and apply your code in the first view controller's initializer:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder:coder)
        let tabFont = UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: 14)!
        tabBarItem.setTitleTextAttributes([.font: tabFont,
                                           .foregroundColor: UIColor.yellow],
                                          for: .selected)
        tabBarItem.setTitleTextAttributes([.font: tabFont,
                                           .foregroundColor: UIColor.white],
                                          for: UIControl.State.normal)
    }
}
```

On iOS 12, the tab bar item text is yellow when selected and white when not selected. But in iOS 13, the bar item text is gray when not selected.

I have not found a satisfactory way to solve this. As suggested in a comment, you can say something like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = .white
}
```

But that's too broad a brush, because it tints *all* tab bar items and it tints the image too.

You can try using the new UITabBarItemAppearance class, but that has other undesirable side effects.

So apart from filing a bug report, there's not much you can do.